# Graphite combining multiple metrics into a single dashboard

Tags: metrics, graphite

My current dashboard graphite file looks like this and aggregates the 200 and 300 series Apache response codes across our dms pool of servers:

```
title   "Aggregated Codes for Pool: dms"
vtitle  "Code Rate (count/sec)"
area    :none  
height  400
width   800

#graph lines
field :response_code,
 :alias => '200s & 300s',
 :data => "sumSeriesWithWildcards(stats.web.response_code.dms.{2*,3*},4)";
```

In the same dashboard I would like a trending line for other response code series possibilities, like those in the 400 and 500 series of codes.

I have tried many ways to get this to build, but none have been successful. And not may examples of doing this available.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring graphite dashboard, which is more likely "general software" related rather then development-related

Comment: May be why I have no luck getting answers. Thanks!